# Eigenvalues of the following matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have to find the eigenvalues of the matrix

$$
I+xx^T/||x||^2
$$

With x being a column vector of size n and I an identity matrix of size nxn. The eigenvalues are supposed to be easily found and be $\lambda_n= 2$ and $\lambda_1=1$, with the rest of eigenvalues inside that range

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: where you have $xx^T$, thats the tensor product right?, i.e. $xx^T\in\Bbb R^{n\times n}$

Comment: Doesn't $x^T$ denote the transpose of $x$? That is, if $x$ is a column vector, then $x^T$ is a row vector.

Comment: yes, but when you have $xx^T$ you are multiplying an $n\times 1$ array with a $1\times n$ array producing and $n\times n$ array, I'm  just checking you don't have it the wrong way round, and what you actually mean is $x^Tx\in\Bbb R$ and $x^Tx=\|x\|^2$

Comment: Hint: Look at how the matrix transforms $x$, and how it transforms any vector orthogonal to $x$. This will yield all eigenvalues.

Comment: The way it is is correct, creating a n x n matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $xx^T/||x||^2$ is a matrix with rank $1$, so there is exactly a non-zero eigen-value and zero eigen-values with multiciplity $n-1$. Since $(xx^T/||x||^2)x=x$ then the non-zero eigen value of $xx^T/||x||^2$ is $1$. Moreover, since for any matrix $A$, $\lambda$ is eigen value of $A$ iff $1+\lambda$ is eigen value of $I+A$ then the eigen values of $I+xx^T/||x||^2$ are $2$ with multiplicity $1$ and $1$ with multiplicity $n-1$.

Answer (score 1):

We can divide the space into $x$ and $n-1$ vectors that are orthogonal to $x$.

For $x$ we have that $(I+\frac{xx^T}{||x||^2})x = x + \frac x {||x||^2} x^Tx = 2x$.

For any $x^\perp$ we have $(I+\frac{xx^T}{||x||^2})x^\perp = x^\perp + \frac x {||x||^2} x^Tx^\perp = x^\perp$.

So we have one eigenvalue 2 with eigenvector $x$ and we have (n-1) eigenvalues 1 with corresponding eigenvectors perpendicular to $x$.